# boost::ext:di create object with shared_ptr parameter through factory extension

Tags: c++, boost, c++17, boost-extension

This code is working fine :

```cpp
// g++ --version == 13.2.1
// g++ -O0 -g3 -std=gnu++20 -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Werror -Wfatal-errors

#include <boost/di/extension/injections/factory.hpp>
#include <cassert>
#include <memory>

class Interface
{
public:
    virtual ~Interface() noexcept = default;
};

class Implementation : public Interface
{
public:
    Implementation(int value) : value_(value) {}
    int value_ = 0;
};

class Example
{
public:
    Example(const boost::di::extension::ifactory<Interface, int>& f)
    {
        auto impl = f.create(87);
        assert(dynamic_cast<Implementation*>(impl.get()));
    }
};

namespace di = boost::di;

int main()
{
    auto injector = di::make_injector(di::bind<di::extension::ifactory<Interface, int>>().to(
        di::extension::factory<Implementation>()));
    auto example = injector.create<std::unique_ptr<Example>>();
    assert(example);
}
```

But this one does not compile :

```cpp
#include <boost/di/extension/injections/factory.hpp>
#include <cassert>
#include <memory>

class Interface
{
public:
    virtual ~Interface() noexcept = default;
};

class Implementation : public Interface
{
public:
    Implementation(std::shared_ptr<int> value) : value_(move(value)) {}
    std::shared_ptr<int> value_;
};

class Example
{
public:
    Example(const boost::di::extension::ifactory<Interface, std::shared_ptr<int>>& f)
    {
        auto ptr = std::make_shared<int>(87);
        auto impl = f.create(std::shared_ptr<int>(ptr));  // can i just pass `ptr` ?
        assert(dynamic_cast<Implementation*>(impl.get()));
    }
};

namespace di = boost::di;

int main()
{
    auto injector =
        di::make_injector(di::bind<di::extension::ifactory<Interface, std::shared_ptr<int>>>().to(
            di::extension::factory<Implementation>()));
    auto example = injector.create<std::unique_ptr<Example>>();
    assert(example);
}
```

Output is :

```
In file included from /deps/di/extension/include/boost/di/extension/injections/factory.hpp:11,
                 from /test.cpp:1:
/deps/di/include/boost/di.hpp: In instantiation of ‘struct boost::ext::di::v1_3_0::aux::concept_check<boost::ext::di::v1_3_0::concepts::type_<std::shared_ptr<int> >::has_disallowed_qualifiers>’:
/deps/di/include/boost/di.hpp:1998:9:   required from ‘std::unique_ptr<I> boost::ext::di::v1_3_0::extension::factory_impl<TInjector, T, boost::ext::di::v1_3_0::extension::ifactory<I, TArgs ...> >::create(TArgs&& ...) const [with TInjector = boost::ext::di::v1_3_0::core::injector<boost::ext::di::v1_3_0::config, boost::ext::di::v1_3_0::core::pool<boost::ext::di::v1_3_0::aux::type_list<> >, boost::ext::di::v1_3_0::core::dependency<boost::ext::di::v1_3_0::scopes::instance, boost::ext::di::v1_3_0::extension::ifactory<Interface, std::shared_ptr<int> >, boost::ext::di::v1_3_0::extension::factory<Implementation>, boost::ext::di::v1_3_0::no_name, void, boost::ext::di::v1_3_0::core::none> >; T = Implementation; I = Interface; TArgs = {std::shared_ptr<int>}]’
/deps/di/extension/include/boost/di/extension/injections/factory.hpp:30:22:   required from here
/deps/di/include/boost/di.hpp:379:20: error: static assertion failed: constraint not satisfied
  379 |   static_assert(T::value, "constraint not satisfied");
      |                    ^~~~~
/deps/di/include/boost/di.hpp:379:20: note: ‘boost::ext::di::v1_3_0::aux::integral_constant<bool, false>::value’ evaluates to false
/deps/di/include/boost/di.hpp: In instantiation of ‘std::unique_ptr<I> boost::ext::di::v1_3_0::extension::factory_impl<TInjector, T, boost::ext::di::v1_3_0::extension::ifactory<I, TArgs ...> >::create(TArgs&& ...) const [with TInjector = boost::ext::di::v1_3_0::core::injector<boost::ext::di::v1_3_0::config, boost::ext::di::v1_3_0::core::pool<boost::ext::di::v1_3_0::aux::type_list<> >, boost::ext::di::v1_3_0::core::dependency<boost::ext::di::v1_3_0::scopes::instance, boost::ext::di::v1_3_0::extension::ifactory<Interface, std::shared_ptr<int> >, boost::ext::di::v1_3_0::extension::factory<Implementation>, boost::ext::di::v1_3_0::no_name, void, boost::ext::di::v1_3_0::core::none> >; T = Implementation; I = Interface; TArgs = {std::shared_ptr<int>}]’:
/deps/di/extension/include/boost/di/extension/injections/factory.hpp:30:22:   required from here
/deps/di/include/boost/di.hpp:1998:9: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘struct boost::ext::di::v1_3_0::aux::concept_check<boost::ext::di::v1_3_0::concepts::type_<std::shared_ptr<int> >::has_disallowed_qualifiers>’
 1998 |         bind
      |         ^~~~
```

How to fix this code ? Thanks for your replies.

Regards,

XS

Comment: The message suggests that the bind argument is not suitable, a "boundable" concept is unmet, specifically checking for `has_disallowed_qualifiers` on the `shared_ptr<int>`. I'm not sure what it should tell you, but there goes

Comment: Oh, and to "just pass `ptr`" `std::move(ptr)` it, or indeed avoid the temporary variable `ptr`

Comment: Some docs? https://boost-ext.github.io/di/user_guide.html#di_boundable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best I understand from playing around with many (*many*) setups, including ditching the factory at all, is that you're simply not supposed to (smart) bind pointers to primitives, which is what the factory ends up doing too. You're supposed to bind pointers to *interfaces*.

You can probably trick the system by wrapping your pointer in a value type, like this:

**[Live On Compiler Explorer](https://compiler-explorer.com/z/7xExexhTM)**

```cpp
#include "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/boost-ext/di/cpp14/include/boost/di.hpp"
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
namespace di = boost::di;

template <typename T> struct Wrapped {
    std::shared_ptr<T> value;
    explicit Wrapped(T v = {}) : value(std::make_shared<T>(std::move(v))) {}

    // for debug output
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Wrapped const& a) {
        return a.value ? os << *a.value : os << "#";
    }
};

// using Arg = int;
using Arg = Wrapped<int>;

struct Interface {
    virtual ~Interface() noexcept = default;
};

struct Implementation : Interface {
    Implementation(Arg value) : value_(std::move(value)) {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "(" << value_ << ")" << std::endl;
    }
    Arg value_{};
};

struct Example {
    Example(std::unique_ptr<Interface> impl) {
        assert(dynamic_cast<Implementation*>(impl.get()));
    }
};

int main() {
    static_assert(di::concepts::boundable<Arg>::value);

    auto injector = make_injector( //
        di::bind<int>().to(42),    //
        di::bind<Interface>()      //
            .to<Implementation>()  //
    );

    auto example = injector.create<std::unique_ptr<Example>>();
    assert(example);
}
```

Printing

```
Implementation::Implementation(Arg)(42)
```

### Back With The Factory

In case you really want the injectee to instantiate dynamic number of instances without directly sharing the entire injector by reference:

```cpp
#include <boost/di.hpp>
#include <boost/di/extension/injections/factory.hpp>
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
namespace di = boost::di;

template <typename T> struct Wrapped {
    std::shared_ptr<T> value;
    /*explicit*/ Wrapped(T v = {}) : value(std::make_shared<T>(std::move(v))) {}

    // for debug output
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Wrapped const& a) {
        return a.value ? os << *a.value : os << "#";
    }
};

// using Arg = int;
using Arg = Wrapped<int>;

struct Interface {
    virtual ~Interface() noexcept = default;
};

using TFactory = di::extension::ifactory<Interface>;

struct Implementation : Interface {
    Implementation(Arg value) : value_(std::move(value)) {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "(" << value_ << ")" << std::endl;
    }
    Arg value_{};
};

struct Example {
    Example(TFactory const& f) {
        std::generate_n(back_inserter(impls), 10, [&f]{ return f.create(); });
    }
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Interface>> impls;
};

int main() {
    static_assert(di::concepts::boundable<Arg>::value);

    auto injector = make_injector(                        //
        di::bind<int>().to(43),                           //
        di::bind<TFactory>()                              //
            .to(di::extension::factory<Implementation>()) //
    );

    auto example = injector.create<std::unique_ptr<Example>>();
    assert(example);
}
```

Printing

```
Implementation::Implementation(Arg)(43)
Implementation::Implementation(Arg)(43)
Implementation::Implementation(Arg)(43)
Implementation::Implementation(Arg)(43)
Implementation::Implementation(Arg)(43)
Implementation::Implementation(Arg)(43)
Implementation::Implementation(Arg)(43)
Implementation::Implementation(Arg)(43)
Implementation::Implementation(Arg)(43)
Implementation::Implementation(Arg)(43)
Implementation::Implementation(Arg)(43)
```

### And With Unbound `Arg`

Of course this again works with the constructor argument as long as the `Arg` satisfies the `boundable` constraint again:

```cpp
using TFactory = di::extension::ifactory<Interface, Arg>;

struct Example {
    Example(TFactory const& f) {
        generate_n(                   //
            back_inserter(impls), 10, //
            [i = 0, &f]() mutable { return f.create(42 * i++); });
    }
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Interface>> impls;
};

int main() {
    static_assert(di::concepts::boundable<Arg>::value);

    auto injector = make_injector(                        //
        di::bind<TFactory>()                              //
            .to(di::extension::factory<Implementation>()) //
    );

    auto example = injector.create<std::unique_ptr<Example>>();
    assert(example);
}
```

Printing

```
Implementation::Implementation(Arg)(0)
Implementation::Implementation(Arg)(42)
Implementation::Implementation(Arg)(84)
Implementation::Implementation(Arg)(126)
Implementation::Implementation(Arg)(168)
Implementation::Implementation(Arg)(210)
Implementation::Implementation(Arg)(252)
Implementation::Implementation(Arg)(294)
Implementation::Implementation(Arg)(336)
Implementation::Implementation(Arg)(378)
```

Comment: With some more understanding and sleep, I wonder whether you just want to treat the factory as a dependency (rather than synthesizing a factory from an injector, which the extension does): then you no longer need "boundable" constructor arguments e.g. https://compiler-explorer.com/z/voT66MMY4.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My class example will read some file on disk and according to found data, will instanciate different implementation of the same interface. So Example class will create Implementation in its constructor. Construction parameter value are only known at Example constructor end.